# Portal host doesn't render template portal in Material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material

Demo Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ye8MAUmrMEQKnPt93TjT?p=preview

I'm referencing the Material 2 documentation to try to set up a template portal that gets rendered in a nearby host (actual usage is not so direct, I want to grab the TemplateRef and hand it off to another component, but for now I just want to get this simplified version working).

```
<ng-template portal #portalEntry>
  <p>hello world</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-template [cdkPortalHost]="portalEntry"></ng-template>
```

Based on the docs, this declarative, markup-only implementation should work. But nothing is rendered. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cdkPortalHost` should be either `ComponentPortal` or `TemplatePortal` instance:

I suspect your expect that `#portalEntry` will be `TemplatePortalDirective` instance.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[cdk-portal], [cdkPortal], [portal]',
  exportAs: 'cdkPortal',
})
export class TemplatePortalDirective extends TemplatePortal {
  constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    super(templateRef, viewContainerRef);
  }
}
```

But it won't work because in your case `portalEntry` is `TemplateRef`

I see several options to solve it:

1) Using `exportAs`

```
#portalEntry="cdkPortal"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/FDj0k5rodYbxQFInBy9S?p=preview)**

2) `@ViewChild`

```
@ViewChild(TemplatePortalDirective) portalEntry: TemplatePortalDirective;
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/J4Wq5ee4cBI7Vq3pZ2K9?p=preview)**